# Accordion expands in wrong direction for first element only

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a table of rows listing information about classifiers for a policy. The ng-repeat directive displays the rows 2 at a time per classifier, where the second row contains a subtable that is hidden unless the fi-chevron arrow for that row gets clicked. The first row contains basic info about the classifier. The second row contains additional information that only displays if requested. This information is in the form of a subtable listing of rules for that classifier.

For some reason, only when clicking the arrow on the first classifier does the table expand ABOVE the classifier info and not below. All other rows, it expands below as it should. This makes no sense because the HTML below forces the order to be where the classifier info row always is on top of the rules table row.

I am using datatables to display the table.

```
<table id="classifier-association-table" class="row-border hover info dataTable no-footer"
     style="border-top: 2px solid #CCC;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th ng-click="sortAttachedSG('name')">
                <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                <div>{{ 'CLASSIFIER_NAME' | translate }}</div>
                <div ng-class="sgAttachedCondition ? 'sort-ascend' : 'sort-descend'" id="sortName"
                     class="sort-icon" style="display: block;" ng-show="sgAttachedNameSort">
                    <span class="fi-chevron"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sortAttachedSG('description')">
                <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                <div>{{ 'CLASSIFIER_TYPE' | translate }}</div>
                <div ng-class="sgAttachedCondition ? 'sort-ascend' : 'sort-descend'" id="sortDesc"
                     class="sort-icon" style="display: block;" ng-show="sgAttachedDescSort">
                    <span class="fi-chevron"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in classifierData" data-ng-switch on="attachedRulesCollapse[$index]">
        <tr ng-class="getSelectedClass(group)">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isSelected(item)"
                       ng-click="checkclick($event,item)" >
                <div class="rules-accordion-arrow"
                     ng-class="attachedRulesCollapse[$index] ? 'sort-ascend' : ''"
                     ng-click="showRulesForClassifier($index, item, true)" id="showRulesId">
                    <span class="fi-chevron"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="name-overflow">{{item.name}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="name-overflow">{{item.type}}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-switch-when="true">
            <td colspan="3">
                <div class="la-ball-clip-rotate icon-button" ng-show='rulesLoadingFlag'
                             style="height: 20px;margin-top: -7px; padding-left: 30rem">
                    <div style="width : 25px;height: 25px;" ng-show="true"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-conainer" id="rulesTable" ng-show="!rulesLoadingFlag">
                    <table id='rules-table' class="row-border hover info dataTable no-footer">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                                    <div>{{ 'CLASSIFIER_RULES_IP_PROTOCOL' | translate }}</div>
                                    <div class="sort-icon"><span class="fi-chevron"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                                    <div>{{ 'CLASSIFIER_RULES_IP_PROTOCOL_NUMBER' | translate }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sort-icon"><span class="fi-chevron"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                                    <div class="ng-binding">
                                        {{ 'CLASSIFIER_RULES_SOURCE_IP' | translate }}
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                                        <div>{{'CLASSIFIER_RULES_SOURCE_PORT' | translate}}
                                            <span id="portRangeToolTipId"
                                                class="fi-help port-range-tooltip"
                                                tabindex="0"
                                                tooltip-class="vtsTooltip"
                                                tooltip="{{'SECURITY_GROUPS_RULES_TOOLTIP' |
                                                    translate}}"
                                                tooltip-append-to-body="true"
                                                tooltip-placement="top-right"
                                                tooltip-trigger="mouseenter focus mouseleave blur">
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                                    <div>{{ 'CLASSIFIER_RULES_DESTINATION_IP' | translate }}</div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="table-vertical-line"></div>
                                    <div>{{ 'CLASSIFIER_RULES_DESTINATION_PORT' | translate }}
                                        <span id="portRangeToolTipId"
                                            class="fi-help port-range-tooltip"
                                            tabindex="0"
                                            tooltip-class="vtsTooltip"
                                            tooltip="{{'SECURITY_GROUPS_RULES_TOOLTIP' |
                                                translate}}"
                                            tooltip-append-to-body="true"
                                            tooltip-placement="top-right"
                                            tooltip-trigger="mouseenter focus mouseleave blur">
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in rules" ng-class="getSelectedClass(rule)">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="name-overflow" data-x-rule-id={{item['rule-id']}}>
                                        {{item.protocol}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="name-overflow">{{item.protcolnumber}}</td>
                                <td ng-bind="item['source-ip']" class="name-overflow"></td>
                                <td class="name-overflow">
                                    <span>{{ item['source-port-range'] }}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td ng-bind="item['destination-ip']" class="name-overflow"></td>
                                <td class="name-overflow">
                                    <span>{{ item['destination-port-range'] }}</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-show="!rules.length && isEditMode">
                                <td class="dataTables_empty" colspan="8">
                                    {{'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_IN_TABLE' | translate}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-show="!isEditMode">
                                <td class="dataTables_empty" colspan="8">
                                    {{'CLASSIFIER_CREATE_RULES_DISABLED' | translate}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: First row expansion]

[image: All other row expansions]

I suspect this may be an angular issue, but I'm not sure. If you would like more code let me know.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: the issue is in the javascript appending the html to the page. For some reason it does not find the html attributes on the first row, instead on the above `table` html element. You need to clearly show us the code responsible for appending this html to the page.

Comment: Can you create a working jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: This is not an AngularJS issue, it is a CSS issue. Inspect the element in the Developer Console. Use the computed style pane to determine the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the `ng-show` directives with `ng-if`, just to try? The difference between them may help narrow the source of the problem to either JS or CSS. Also, would it be possible to add a JSON listing with one record of sample data?